# кодирование урлов

Tags: php

Надо в ресайзер картинок в цикле закидывать картинки с чужого сервера, если они "плохие", то сваливать в отдельную функцию, которая делает их "хорошими". Пример плохой картинки `http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/ЛГ-06пр..png` или `http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/1020 СD_garbage bags_60L_40pcs.jpg`. Сами картинки хорошие, плохие у них урлы.

Для ресайзера мне по-любому надо пройтись по картинке функцией get_headers(), а она такие урлы не хавает. Казалось бы всё просто: втыкнул urlencode() и порядок, но не тут то было. urlencode() все не цифро-буквенные символы, кроме -_ декодирует, в том числе и схему (протокол), это тоже легко обходится

```
private function urlencode($url) {

    $url='http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/ЛГ-06пр..png';  // тест

    $a = (string) 'https://';
    $b = (string) 'http://';
    $https = stripos($url, $a);
    $http = stripos($url, $b);

    if ($https !== false) {$num = 8; $c = $a;}
    if ($http !== false) {$num = 7; $c = $b;}

    $url = str_replace('%20',' ',$url);     //возвращаем пробелы на место 
    $url = mb_strcut($url, $num, null);     //отрезаем протокол
    $url = urlencode($url);                 //кодируем хвост
    $url = (string) $с.$url;                //возвращаем протокол на место

    print_r($url);
    //        print_r(stream_get_meta_data(fopen($url,"r")));die();
    print_r(get_headers($url));die();
    //        return $url;
}
```

в итоге получаем кодированный урл, но get_headers() опять его не хочет. Пробовал stream_get_meta_data(), тоже не то. Обе приведенные картинки (с русскими буквами и пробелами в урле открываются браузером). Если взять урл, который создал браузер для открытия картинки, т.е. с %20 и скормить его в get_headers(), то опять же ответ сервера 404. Не понятно, для чего вообще тогда функция urlencode() и в какой вид мне надо преобразовать урл, чтоб он обработался функцией get_headers(). Пожалуйста, подскажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо кодировать не всю ссылку, а только не корректную часть. 
(После обработки `urlencode` заменяем проставленные `+` вместо пробелов на `%20` и оба варианта ссылок будут работать корректно)
Обратите внимание на комментарии:

```php
//$url='http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/1020 СD_garbage bags_60L_40pcs.jpg';
$url='http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/ЛГ-06пр..png';  // тест

$bz = explode('/', $url); // Разделяем на части
$last = array_pop($bz); // Получаем последнюю часть
$url1 = urlencode($last); // Кодируем её
$new = array_push($bz, $url1); //Добавляем обратно
$url2 = implode('/', $bz); // Объединяем массив обратно в строку

$url3 = str_replace('+','%20',$url2);     // заменяем + после urlencode на %20
print_r(get_headers($url3));die();
```

Вы можете енкодировать всё кроме основного домена, через перебор массива с нужного индекса. 
Вот пример:

```php
//$url='http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/1020 СD_garbage bags_60L_40pcs.jpg';
$url='http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/ЛГ-06пр..png';  // тест

$bz = explode('/', $url); // Разделяем на части
for ($i = 3; $i < count($bz); $i++){
    $tempUrl = urlencode($bz[$i]); // Кодируем части
    $bz[$i] = $tempUrl; //Заменяем старые части url на енкодированные
}
$url2 = implode('/', $bz); // Объединяем массив обратно в строку
print_r($url2);

$url3 = str_replace('+','%20',$url2);     // заменяем + после urlencode на %20
print_r(get_headers($url3));die();
```

Comment: хы... работает, получается энкодить надо только "проблемную" часть урла, а не весь урл. Но, есть момент. Учитывая, что мы критично относимся к данным приходящим извне, то мы можем предположить, что урл может быть "плохим" не только после последнего "/", но и где-то в середине или в начале. В таком случае этот код не сработает. Надо брать массив и через foreach перебирать таким способом каждую его часть?

Comment: @Oughtem не совсем правильно выразился - Вы можете подвергнуть `urlencode` всё кроме основной части домена. Те части, которые были не корректны - изменятся, остальные останутся такими же. Добавил пример в ответ.